# E-Mail report sending with Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm working with a Django project using Python 3.8.2 and I need to send emails every day (they contain a simple csv file with some data). I wanted to use Celery, but it doesn't support my python version and downgrading isn't really possible at the moment. Is there any other practical way to do this?

Let me know if I'm not being specific enough or the question is badly formulated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can always create a custom management command to send emails. You can use cron to call that command daily.

Comment: OK, I'll try that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send messages via Django, you can use gmail or your own SMTP:

in settings:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'foo@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '**************'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

*For google to allow sending emails from this address you will have to access your account> Access and security> Option Allow access to less secure applications: ON

Then you just have to go to your views and:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

email = EmailMessage('title', 'body', to=[email])
email.send()

en tu view:

from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
class contacto(View):
    def get(self,request):
        form=correo()
        return render(request,'email.html',{'forma':form})
    def post(self,request):
        form=correo(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            datos=form.cleaned_data

            email = EmailMessage('title', 'body', to=[email])
            email.send()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        return render(request,'email.html',{'forma':form})
```

To program task from django i use cron.

Install [runscript](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html) and make a script that fits your needs. Now you can launch it by:

```
python manage.py runscript <<script_name>> --script-args <<args>>
```

Then just add your script to your cron:

```
#Every day at 22h
* * 22 * *      cd /path/to/project; python manage.py runscript send_mail
```

Comment: Thanks! I was already sending emails for another porpouse, though

Comment: The question is how to do it daily

Comment: No lo implementé porque tengo windows y no tiene mucho sentido hacerlo ahora. Voy a setearlo cuando esté en producción (Creo que usaré Heroku) y tenga la terminal linux de ahí. Lo que hice fue crear un "custom managament command" y lo único que queda es crear la tarea de cron.